Holomorphic section of product tensor bundle
Let $E \to X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over a complex manifold $X$, and let $L \to X$ be a holomorphic line bundle. Assume that $\mathcal{U}=\{U,V\}$ is an open cover which trivializes holomorphically $L \to X$ with related cocycle
$g_{U,V} \colon U\cap V \to \mathbb{C}^*.$
Now consider $\sigma \colon X \to E$ a holomorphic global section.
On $U \cap V$ obviously holds $\sigma|_U = \sigma|_V$, thus
$$g_{U,V}\cdot\sigma_U=g_{U,V}\cdot\sigma_V. \tag{1}$$
How does the pair $\{\tau_U :=g_{UV}\cdot\sigma_U, \tau_V:=\sigma_V\}$ yield a holomorphic global section $\tau \colon X \to E\otimes L$?
I recognize that condition $(1)$ is similar to the gluing condition $s_\alpha = g_{\alpha\beta}s_\beta$ but in this case $s_\alpha,s_\beta$ are not holomorphic functions. I cannot convince myself with a decent proof that such a section exists.

This follows straightaway from the definition, i.e. the gluing condition.
